# Connect.registerUsers - Need helping creating array for accounts param

Tags: java, facebook, json

I keep getting the following error when I try to invoke the Facebook REST API Call:

[Connect.registerUsers](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect.registerUsers)

**Error Code: 100 - param accounts must be an array**

JSON based response (from Facebook):

```
{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"param accounts must be an array.","request_args":
[{"key":"accounts","value":"{email_hash:5232156322_55ddgvc3db5ddcf218049dd564da2x06}"},
{"key":"api_key","value":"23b2c4c6a23445fbffssf8aab96a5e5"},
{"key":"format","value":"JSON"},{"key":"method","value":"Connect.registerUsers"},{"key":"sig","value":"3sd54153a31382fa6e72eecf3c57d7c9"},{"key":"v","value":"1.0"}],"message":"Unknown exception","code":0}
```

I set up the Java code to invoke the REST end point using HttpClient like this:

```
String API_KEY = "23b2c4c6a23445fbffssf8aab96a5e5";
String toConnectRegisterUsersSignature = 
   "accounts=" 
   + "{email_hash:" +  emailHash + "}"
   + "api_key=" + API_KEY
   + "format=JSON"
   + "method=Connect.registerUsers"
   + "v=1.0"
   + "0c786155bd3cxe8228d924542da5gf2";

String connectRegisterUsersSignature = SimpleMd5.MD5(toConnectRegisterUsersSignature);

NameValuePair[] connectRegisterUsersParameters =
{ 
    new NameValuePair("accounts", "{email_hash:" +  emailHash + "}"),
    new NameValuePair("api_key", API_KEY),
    new NameValuePair("format", "JSON"),
    new NameValuePair("method", "Connect.registerUsers"),
    new NameValuePair("sig", connectRegisterUsersSignature),
    new NameValuePair("v", "1.0") 
};
```

Tried the following combinations and I still get the same error!

```
Signature: "accounts=" + "[email_hash=" + emailHash + "]"
new NameValuePair("accounts", "[email_hash=" + emailHash + "]")

Signature: "accounts=" + "email_hash[" + emailHash + "]"
new NameValuePair("accounts", "email_hash[" + emailHash + "]")

Signature: "accounts=" + "email_hash(" + emailHash + ")"
new NameValuePair("accounts", "email_hash(" + emailHash + ")")

Signature: "accounts=" + "[email_hash=" + emailHash + "]"
new NameValuePair("accounts", "[email_hash=" + emailHash + "]")

Signature: "accounts=" + "email_hash=" + emailHash
new NameValuePair("accounts", "email_hash=" + emailHash)

Signature: "accounts=" + "[{email_hash:" +  emailHash + "}]"
new NameValuePair("accounts", "[{email_hash:" +  emailHash + "}]"),
```

Does anyone know how to construct this array that the response is requesting?

Happy programming and thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much help this will be, but the following works for me in Python using the [PyFacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) wrapper (sorry, not familiar with the Java method):

```
hashed_email = facebook.hash_email('mary@example.com')
# >>> hashed_email
# >>> '4228600737_c96da02bba97aedfd26136e980ae3761'
regaccounts = [{"email_hash": hashed_email}] 

facebook.connect.registerUsers(regaccounts)
```

The PyFacebook wrapper sends the api_key (which, incidently is the only other [required parameter](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect.registerUsers))

P.S. If it's any consolation, your question made me realise where I'd gone wrong in a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625742/facebook-api-registerusers-error-100-invalid-email-hash)!